# Excel VBA - Split strings in a range at a white space, considering all cells in the range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, split, delimiter

I am extracting many tables from a pdf, which I need to import into a database. Because of the extraction, some come out quite badly.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofY1g.png)

I would like to have a VBA script that loops through all cells in the worksheet containing strings and splitting these at the white space, so that any values after the space are removed from the cell and put in the adjacent cells to the right.

I have looked into the SPLIT function in combination with a loop, but I am stuck because my VBA knowledge is quite little.

Comment: You may want to look into "text to columns"

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but as you can see in the image, the spaces are not always the same in the entire column, so it will overwrite other cells. That is why I think a loop through the individual cells is necessary.

Comment: In your sample image, you would need to copy the six bottom most cells of the last column four rows to the right anyways so do that before apply text to columns to the row before it. I extract PDFs on a daily basis -- there is no painless way to do it...

Comment: Use Text to Columns, Delimited. Select Space as a delimiter and also Other. Put a non-breaking space in to Other. Use *Teat consecutive delimiters as one*.

Comment: In this case, it does not work, see image. Moreover, I have a lot of these, so I would like to use a VBA script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're struggling to get an answer so I'm happy to try and help.

Create a new module in the VBA project and add the below code ...

```
Public Sub SplitCells()
    Dim rngSrcData As Range, objDestSheet As Worksheet, lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long, arrSplit, arrData(), lngWriteRow As Long, lngIndex As Long
    Dim strDelimiter As String, i As Long, strWriteRange As String

    Set rngSrcData = Selection
    Set objDestSheet = Worksheets("Output")
    strDelimiter = " "

    objDestSheet.Cells.Clear

    With rngSrcData
        For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            lngIndex = 0

            For lngCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                arrSplit = Split(CStr(.Cells(lngRow, lngCol)), strDelimiter, , vbTextCompare)

                For i = 0 To UBound(arrSplit)
                    ReDim Preserve arrData(lngIndex)
                    arrData(lngIndex) = arrSplit(i)

                    lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
                Next
            Next

            lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1

            strWriteRange = .Cells(lngWriteRow, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(lngWriteRow, UBound(arrData) + 1).Address
            objDestSheet.Range(strWriteRange) = arrData
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

... along with the above, create a new worksheet in your workbook and call it "**Output**".  That's the destination for the transformed data.

Now select your entire data range (as you showed in your screen shot) and then run the macro.

[image]

Check your "Output" sheet and you should see your result.

I hope it works for you.